# Oracle PL/SQL wrapper function for Java program that retuns byte array

Tags: java, oracle

I have a Java program which reads a file from SFTP and returns a byte array - Max file size is 2MB.
I want to write an Oracle wrapper SQL function for this method.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION SFTPDownloadFile(host varchar2, account varchar2, fileName varchar2) return BLOB is 
LANGUAGE JAVA NAME 'FileAttachment.downloadFile(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String) return byte[]';
/
```

Another PL/SQL procedure calls `SFTPDownloadFile()` and inserts its return data into a table with a BLOB column.

I am reported an error on the line where I call `SFTPDownloadFile()` and assign to a BLOB variable.

> inconsistent datatypes: expected a return value that is convertible to an Oracle BLOB got a Java byte array

How can I get this byte array as a BLOB object in Oracle?